# Which is correct: 'haven't done since' or 'haven't done for'?

Tags: phrase-usage

If I want to describe something which I haven't done from a duration of time, then what should I use? Consider example:

> I haven't met my friend since a year.

OR

> I haven't met my friend for a year.

Comment: For is for a period of time such as a year. Since is for a point of time such as 2012. The second example is correct while the first I think is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are referring to duration, use “for” or “in”; when referring to the last time something happened, use “since”. “Since” will always require that you specify a *point* in time, not a *span*.

Your second option is grammatical and perhaps even ideal in BrE. For AmE, if you haven't rendezvoused, visited, or *met up with* your friend in a year, I recommend you say:

> I haven't *seen* my friend **for** a year.

It all depends on exactly what you wish to convey, but some people may associate “meeting” with either the impossible-to-repeat act of making someone's acquaintance or the cold sense of business meetings.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that meet is restricted to the first time only. "We met *for the first time*" is quite a common phrase, so I thought any subsequent instances of seeing someone are also called "met".

Comment: I don't think meet is quite so restricted; you can "meet your friend for lunch", for example.  And there's also "We meet again!" for an occasion where you encounter someone for a second (or third, fourth, etc.) time.  However, I do agree that "meet my friend" is not a normal phrase, I'm just struggling a bit to explain why.

Comment: *I'm meeting my friend for lunch at the deli. It's been a while since we last met. We used to meet every week to talk politics, but we've met less often since she started dating. I've met her boyfriend three times, each more unpleasant than the last.*

Comment: It's certainly possible to communicate other things with this verb, but it's nonetheless important to understand its _default_ implications in order to avoid phrasings that sound a little off. I don't think I'm making a contentious claim to say that _on its own_ this verb tends to convey the idea of making someone's acquaintance.

Comment: @choster I simply can't unequivocally recommend “I haven't met him for a year.” If that doesn't sound even a little odd to you, then maybe I'm finicky, but I have to speak to my experience.

Comment: @choster I contend that those uses are different from what OP seems to be wanting to convey. I've added to my answer in an attempt to explain why I can't recommend “I haven't met him in a year.” Your first example sounds like you're talking about a committee, and the second is obviously business-related. I don't personally think that's the best possible way to talk about having seen (or not seen) a friend.

Comment: Happy and Tyler, I think that using “with” or “up with” after the word *meet*, is a part of American English in particular. Doing so is not common in the UK, so, saying *I haven't met my friend for a year* would be fine.

Comment: @Tristan Not a day goes by I don't come upon a new difference between our respective Englishes! Just yesterday, I **learned** that you spell “furor” **wrong** over there. I've edited my answer again, hopefully to the effect of global satisfaction.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung, I appreciate the edit. This will let people know that the exact wording to choose in the context of the question, will also depend on which English is being used. It is important to learn **and** understand, which is what we can all do here. Not just people who are learning English as a foreign language.

Comment: So does it boil to difference between British English and American English? In other words, "I haven't met my friend for a year" is OK in British English? I am from India, where British English is predominant for obvious reasons.

Comment: On second thoughts, I will ask this as a separate question. It seems interesting enough and shouldn't be lost in the comments.