# Is "haven't met my friend" correct in British English?

Tags: phrase-usage

The discussion in comments to [Tyler James Young](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/2274/tyler-james-young)'s [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13134/205) to this question [Which is correct: 'haven't done since' or 'haven't done for'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13123/205) deserves to be asked as a separate question.

Is the following phrase usage correct in British English (and incorrect in American English)?

> I haven't met my friend for a year.

The point of contention here is the use of `met` when referring to a meeting which is not the first one.

Comment: I'm reluctant to call it "incorrect", but I certainly prefer the versions presented by FumbleFingers in his comment on Tristan's answer.  (I'm a speaker of American English.)

Comment: It's fine.  If you dropped that line into a conversation, nobody would notice anything strange about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Tristan's answer, and comments thereto, it seems there's a range of opinions. So here's my take...

> 1: *I met John yesterday  (we became acquainted/were introduced **for the first time**)*
>    2: *I met with John yesterday  (we had a meeting/discussion **by arrangement**)*
>    3: *I met up with John yesterday  (we came across one another **unexpectedly**)*

The bracketed supplementaries are my default interpretations *in the absence of any other context*, but it's important to note that #1 (by far the most common form) can be used with all three senses. Also, not everyone will recognise my distinction between #2 and #3 (but neither would normally be used in the ***first time*** sense).

Thus I would unhesitatingly say that in OP's context, ***seen*** is the better verb.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with it, from a British perspective. There may be other ways to word it, as well.

Comment: Speaking as another Brit, I don't like OP's usage much. I'd rather hear either *"I haven't **met up with** my friend"*, or *"I haven't **seen** my friend"*.

Comment: FF, your second suggestion sounds better. The words *up* and *with* in the first one are superfluous, surplus to requirements, unnecessary added extras.

Comment: It's not at all "superfluous", given that plain ***meet*** often means *meet **for the first time***. And there's certainly no inherent reason why short forms should always be preferred over long forms.

Comment: I did not intend to give the impression that short forms should always be preferred over long forms. *Up* and *with* in the first one are superfluous, because they do not add any extra meaning. They are not needed. They are just there. There is nothing wrong with wording your suggestion as *I haven't met my friend*. It has the same meaning.

Comment: All I can say is when I search on Google Books for ["I haven't **met** my friend since..."](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+haven't+met+my+friend+since%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) it produces no written instances at all (but it *does* offer this very page as an example of what it found on the Internet at large). But there are plenty of written instances of ["I haven't **seen** my friend since"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+haven't+seen+my+friend+since%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I think ***met*** is at least "slightly odd" in OP's context.

Comment: "up" is redundant in "met up with" and sounds awfully colloquial. "with" is not superfluous because "meet with" implies a prearrangement. You cannot "meet with" someone for the first time, as in "encounter".

Comment: @Kaz: I agree that it would be a contrived context indeed where you could "meet with" someone you've never met before. (Though of course you could feasibly excuse the fact of being late [to arrive/do something] by saying you *met with some problems* - and you wouldn't necessarily want that to be understood as meaning you're familiar with the experience! :) But you're quite right that including ***up*** is a bit colloquial. It could also be seen as emphatically disambiguating though. So I reckon I can usually spare enough breath for that one little extra word, just to be on the safe side!

Comment: FF, my point is that using the word *with* after *meet* or *met*, is unnecessary in the English of the UK. I am aware that Americans do that a lot but, it is not critical. In British English it is just a verbose http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/verbose?q=verbose way of using language.